# Expo - EAS Update - Push changes to TestFlight

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight, eas

I am using the fully managed expo workflow. I am trying to figure out how to use `eas update` to push updates to TestFlight on `ios`.

I have linked all channels to my `main` branch, the update is pushed successfully - however, I don't think it has updated the app within TestFlight.

`eas.json`

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.60.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it in this way:

1. `eas update:configure` and follow all the steps.
2. `eas build --profile production` – don't forget to increase the build number
3. `eas submit -p ios --latest` in order to have the last build on testflight and also make sure you update the app in your phone.
4. `eas update` after this, force close the app 2-3 times and you'll see the changes.

Comment: With everything configured correctly, simply closing and opening the app solved it for me!

Comment: Hi, after doing so i get this in my console: Failed to upload
Asset processing timed out for assets: